# Getting row a where the difference row b_1 minus row b_2 is minimum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
a     b
1     4.5
1     5.1
2     6.2
2     6.4
3     7.1
3     3.2
4     0
4     0
```

For each `'a'` value, there are two dataframe rows. I want to get the `'a'` value where `abs(b1-b2)` is minimum. EDIT: Also, I want to ignore those cases where both `'a'` entries have `'b=0'`.

Is that easily achievable with Pandas?

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.loc[df.groupby('a')['b'].diff().abs().idxmin()]`? which would return row 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on 'a' and call [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) and [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) to return the absolute difference between the pairs of values, you can then get the index using [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
In [127]:
df.loc[df.groupby('a')['b'].diff().abs().idxmin()]

Out[127]:
a    2.0
b    6.4
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

The intermediate steps and output are:

```
In [128]:
df.groupby('a')['b'].diff()

Out[128]:
0    NaN
1    0.6
2    NaN
3    0.2
4    NaN
5   -3.9
dtype: float64

In [129]:    
df.groupby('a')['b'].diff().abs()

Out[129]:
0    NaN
1    0.6
2    NaN
3    0.2
4    NaN
5    3.9
dtype: float64

In [130]:    
df.groupby('a')['b'].diff().abs().idxmin()

Out[130]:
3
```

**EDIT**

To handle the case where you have 2 `0` values you'd have to filter these out, essentially performing a double groupby:

```
In [157]:
df.loc[df[df['a'].isin(df.loc[df.groupby('a')['b'].diff().abs() > 0,'a'])].groupby('a')['b'].diff().abs().idxmin()]

Out[157]:
a    2.0
b    6.4
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It works but... I'm getting NaN for some pairs. First I though it was due to getting diff from 0 and 0 values, but it is not the case... any idea?

Comment: It means you have missing pairs

Comment: You could try `df['a'].value_counts() < 2` to see where you don't have a pairs

Comment: Ok, false alarm. But I do have a problem: how to avoid considering those cases where b_1 = 0 and b_2 = 0?